# Trying to link a variable within a label to a button

Tags: ios, swift

I’m a newer developer and I’m trying to figure out how to navigate to a specific `CollectionView` based on a randomly generated variable within a label.

I created a button that generates a random weather pattern and within there is a `weatherType` variable that’s randomly generated and when the labels `weatherType` is “Sunny”, “Windy”, “Rainy”, or “Cloud” I want to be able to press another button that will take the user to a `SunnyCollectionView`, ‘RainCollectionView’,’WindCollectionView’, or ‘CloudCollectionView’.

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {

    @IBOutlet weak var firstLabel: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var weatherInfoLabel: UILabel!
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
    }
    
    @IBAction func weatherButton(_ sender: Any) {
        let weatherVar = Weather()
        firstLabel.text = weatherVar.weatherInfo()
    }
    
    @IBAction func clothingCollectionButton() {
        let weatherVar = Weather()
        let storyBoard : UIStoryboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle:nil)

        if weatherVar.randomWeatherType == "Sunny" {
            let nextViewController = storyBoard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "SunCollectionView") as! SunCollectionViewController
            self.present(nextViewController, animated:true, completion:nil)
        }
    }
```

From here, I’m able to use the `weatherButton` to get a random weather type but I want to use the `clothingCollectionButton` to take me to the next collection view based on that weather.
When I’m simulating and I hit the clothingCollectionButton, it does not take me to the CollectionView based on the random weatherType within the label.

Could anyone help? What I have up is what I thought would work but it hasn’t.

Comment: Explain what goes wrong where.  Is `nextViewController` instantiated for example?

Comment: Have you used the debugger with this? Or added some print statements? Is `clothingCollectionButton` getting executed? Is `weatherVar.randomWeatherType` actually equal to "Sunny"?

Comment: Just edited, the randomWeather type  inside of the firstLabel will be random each time the weatherButton is tapped.